# Excel to Access VBA Loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to write some code that uses an excel template to upload data to an access DB. I'm somewhat new to VB so I got the code offline and tailored it to my needs. When I try to run it I am receiving a "Compile error: Do without loop" error message. Please advise as to what I am doing wrong.

All help is greatly appreciated!

```
Sub UploadtoAccess()
'
' UploadtoAccess Macro
'
'Sub ADOFromExcelToAccess()'
' exports data from the active worksheet to a table in an Access database
' this procedure must be edited before use
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, r As Long
    ' connect to the Access database
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "provider = microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\Users\filepath (full file path taken out)
    ' open a recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "Expenses", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
    ' all records in a table
    r = 2 ' the start row in the worksheet
    Do While Len(Range(“A” & r).Formula) > 0
    Do While Len(Range(“B” & r).Formula) > 0
    Do While Len(Range(“C” & r).Formula) > 0
    Do While Len(Range(“D” & r).Formula) > 0
    ' repeat until first empty cell in column A
        With rs
            .AddNew ' create a new record
            ' add values to each field in the record
            .Fields("Expense_Type_ID") = Range("A" & r).Value
            .Fields("Expense_Type") = Range(“B” & r).Value
            .Fields(“Expense_Month”) = Range(“C” & r).Value
            .Fields(“Expense_Amount”) = Range(“D” & r).Value
            ' add more fields if necessary…
            .Update ' stores the new record
        End With
        r = r + 1 ' next row
    Loop
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You have 4 instances of `Do While` but only one instance of `Loop`.

Comment: ...and you have "smart quotes" in your code, which don't work as expected in VBA

Comment: @BigBen Thank you for the help! Would I need to set 4 looping variables to correct that?

Comment: What do you want to happen if B,C, or D are empty?

Comment: @NathanSutherland Ideally they should never be empty so I guess I'll need to figure out the code that would call out if a cell in the middle of a data set is empty.

Comment: @BigBen I adjusted the code and it works now. Thanks!

Comment: (You also need to close quote on the line `"Data Source=C:\ ...`)